# Twitter Search 2 Plugin PHP Error (stdClass::$to_user_id_str)

Tags: php, search, error, twitter-search-2

Some of my ExpressionEngine (EE2) websites that run Twitter Search 2 by Exp:resso have recently started throwing out PHP Error Notifications, and I can't see why.

```
A PHP Error Was Encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$to_user_id_str

Filename: twitter_search/pi.twitter_search.php

Line Number: 107
```

The code inside the template is:

```
{exp:twitter_search q="from:@xxxxxx+OR+from:@xxxxxxxx+OR+from:@xxxxxx" rpp="5" lang="en" cache="yes" auto_links="yes"  refresh="5"}

<div class="tweetItem clearfix">
        <a href="{tweet_url}" target="_blank"><img src="{profile_image_url}" width="40" height="40" border="0"/></a>
        <div class="flRight tweetAuthor"><em><a href="{tweet_url}" target="_blank">{from_user}</a></em> - {text}</div>
        <div class="flRight tweetAuthor tweetDate">{relative_tweet_date} ago</div>
</div>

{/exp:twitter_search}
```

Nothing has been changed in the template code or server side, it just started throwing these notices.

I'm wondering whether it could be Twitter API limits as the sites are on the same server, but the tweets are still being pulled and rendered correctly, so it's not just appearing blank.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a point, it's happened to me an hour ago on 3 seperate sites. I think this might be the Twitter API changing..

Answer (score 3):

Twitter's switch to v1.1 of their API isn't supposed to happen until next month, though this may have been one of their "blackout tests". Definitely API related at any rate.

Regardless, [CE Tweet](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-tweet) is the only Twitter add-on I know of that's currently compliant with the API changes. I would strongly recommend migrating.

Comment: Thanks Derek, I actually purchased CE Tweet this morning in response to the problem. Haven't had time to test it yet, but it seems that may be the way forward. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed as of 5 minutes ago in v2.0.8 of Twitter Search. You can grab a fresh copy here:

https://github.com/expressodev/twitter_search

It seems there were some slight changes to the Twitter search API results which the plugin wasn't expecting.

Note: Twitter Search uses the Twitter Search API which is completely separate from the main Twitter API (it does not use authentication at all), and therefore should not be affected by the upcoming Twitter API v1.1 changes (AFAIK, only time will tell for sure).

Comment: Cheers Adrian, this has resolved the issue on the sites. Thanks for your quick work.

Comment: Did this answer help solve your issue? If yes, select the answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left.